# Ошибка webpack из-за стороннего файла package.json в каталоге

Tags: node.js, webpack, babel

Есть проект на Node JS(Express),где используется Server-Side-Rendering React компонента. Компонент лежит в каталоге целиком, включая папки `src`, `public_html`, а также файлы `package.json`.

При сборке Webpack-ом, возникает ошибка, якобы во входящем файле react синтаксическая ошибка: `SyntaxError: C:\Users\Admin\node\path\to\script1\src\index.js: Unexpected token (26:3)`

```
  25 |  hydrate(
> 26 |    <Provider store={store}>
     |    ^
  27 |          <App/>
  28 |    </Provider>,
  29 |    document.querySelector('.root')
```

Если файл `package.json` переименовать в `1package.json`, то сборка проходит успешно.

Не совсем понятно, что происходит при сборке. Почему `1package.json` проходит, а `package.json` - нет

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Конфиг Webpack:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
      common: [
               'babel-polyfill',
               './path/to/script/src/index.js'
               ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: "babel-loader" 
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```